# How can I download a video from Facebook using GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook, video, facebook-graph-api

I want to download a video from facebook to the clients local drive. I saw a few browser plugins and Facebook apps that are able to that and I was wondering how it can be done using the GraphAPI or in any other way.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

First, you get the Graph API object.  If the object is `public`, it's simple, just get https://graph.facebook.com/10151651550011063.  (Where the number is the object's ID, equal to the `?v=OBJECTID` in the facebook video URL.)

If the object is not public, you need a valid access_token, and the Graph API url becomes something like `https://graph.facebook.com/10151651550011063?access_token=DFSDSGSFDGFGDSblabla`

Then, in the Graph API object, you'll find the video download link under `source`.

Comment: how get facebook video url? when use webview.

Comment: How to download and play the facebook video using facebook url like coub app is doing in iOS

Comment: @knutole this is now deprecated i think because source key is not returning from above link any idea why ?

Comment: @BunkerBoy Yes, FB changes their API all the time, so this answer is most probably no longer working. I'm not up to date, so you'll have to explore the API for yourself - or google more recent answers.

Comment: i get the video source but it is low quality. idk if it's due to covid-19 throttling or not... but is there a way to get the original video?

Comment: @beppe9000 have you managed to get the higher resolution of it?
Also is there any unofficial API wrapper for python?

Comment: @knutole above method is not working now.. still figuring.. can you please guide.. I am developing an app with asp.net

Comment: I'm getting the source parameter in the Graph API Explorer but not in my actual app. Strange. I have all the permissions, using the same access token etc.

Answer (score 3):

Refer Below Link. Might help you

http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/api/video/

Answer (score 3):

1/ You can get source video by api but it only in sd quality.

2/ If you need to get source video by api, make sure you know to get accesstoken by this way:

- Go to https://m.facebook.com/composer/ocelot/async_loader/?publisher=feed
- Search for EAAA... it is your accesstoken.

3/ https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/(page/group/userid)_videoid?fields=source&access_token=your_accesstoken

example https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/1389311341281276_2668264723385925?fields=source&access_token=your_accesstoken
finally you can get private video or public video from facebook by graph api

Answer (score 1):

$idPage/feed?fields=message,link,created_time,type,name,id,source

source => will return url mp4 video post

Answer (score -3):

You cannot download videos **using api**.
You can just get there links,likes,comments etc.