# How to monitor the GET methods of a URL?

Tags: python, http, url, get, urllib2

Not sure If I'll make sense or not but here goes. In Google chrome, if you rightclick a page and go to resources, then refresh a page, you can see all the GET/POST methods pop up as they happen. I'm wanting to know if there is a way, in python, to input a url and have it generate a list of each get call be listed (not sure if possible)

Would love some direction on it!
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe I can clarify parts of your original question.

One the one hand, using the browser-built-in debugging tools for investigating how a certain website behaves when loaded by a browser is a good technique, and not easily replaceable by custom code.

On the other hand, it looks like you are looking for an HTML parser, such as [BeautifulSoup](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/).

Also, you seem to confuse the meaning of a URL and an HTML document. A URL **can** point to an HTML document, but in many cases it points to other things, such as JSON-API endpoint.

Assuming you actually wanted to ask how *"to input a URL to an HTML document and have it generate a list of each remote resource call a browser would perform"*:

Before rendering a website, a web browser fires off the initial HTTP GET request and retrieves the main HTML document. It parses this document and, among others, searches for further resources to be retrieved. Such resources may be CSS files, JavaScript files, images, iframes, ... (long list). If it finds such resources, the browser automatically fires off one HTTP GET request for *each* of these resources. As you can see, there is quite some work involved and happening behind the scenes, before all these requests are performed by your browser.

In Python, you cannot trivially simulate the behavior of your browser. You can easily retrieve a single HTML document via the `urllib` or `requests` module. That is, you can manually fire off a single HTTP GET request to retrieve an HTML document. Replicating the behavior of a browser would then require

- to parse the HTML document in the same way the browser does,
- to search the document for remote sources such as images, CSS files, ....,
- to decide which remote resources to query in which order, and
- then to fire off even more HTTP GET requests, and possibly *recursively repeat the entire* process (as would be required for iframes)

Exact replication of browser behavior is too complex. Building a proper web browser is an inherently difficult task.

**That is, if you want to understand the behavior of a website within a browser, use the browser's debugging tools.**

Comment: Thank for the reply, it explains a lot to me that I didn't know. The reason I asked the question in the first place is that I'm trying to figure out a way to download public facebook videos with python. And the way I explained is the only way I know how to do it manually and I was kind of hoping to automate it. I'm not sure if you know a better way? I don't need to do this for a single video btw, I would have used a service. I'm doing it so I can use python to download it.

Comment: @Johnny, indeed, what you want is achievable and usually falls under the term "web scraper". You should learn how to parse an HTML document using BeautifulSoup (linked in the answer). Then you will possibly be able to extract URLs to videos and then download those. This will be difficult when a Flash-based video player is involved, because then the URL is usually hidden or the video is only available in streaming format. In the latter case, other technologies are available for automatically retrieving the video data. Google is your friend :-).

Comment: Found it, Just used the Facebook GraphAPI and it worked. Just had to use source haha

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642579/how-can-i-download-a-video-from-facebook-using-graphapi

Comment: This is a complex task, do not expect to find a *reliable* method within one day only. The biggest issue might be the strong usage of JavaScript in a complex web application such as Facebook. It is not really possible to replicate this behavior in Python. You might need to automatically interact with a *real browser* to obtain similar web application behavior as a real user would observe. Might want to have a look at Selenium and its Python bindings.

Comment: Even better: using an official API, if available!

Comment: That's the code using facepy if anyone comes across it. Returns the direct mp4 url :)
http://pastebin.com/nTA0vFCb