# Facebook video source url not showing in FB graph api call

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get direct url of public videos in FB.

Following recommendation in this question,

[How can I download a video from Facebook using GraphAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642579/how-can-i-download-a-video-from-facebook-using-graphapi)

I tried to invoke for the following fields. `source`, `status`, `title` using below url

https://graph.facebook.com/10158167232321509?access_token=xxxxxx&fields=source,status,title

only return `status`, `title` and `id`. No video source url.

Based on the `documentation`,
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/

`source` should be a `string` type containing A `URL` to the raw, playable video file.

Any idea why it is not showing source url?

thanks

Comment: we cant get the source URL of the video by above URL method right? I am trying still not getting

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Any idea why it is not showing source url?

Most likely because you don’t “work at” CNN ...?

As https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/video/#Reading clearly states,

> The source field will not be returned for Page-owned videos unless the User making the request has a role on the owning Page.

Comment: I was mistaken on the context of the word `public`. It turns out FB video labelled public is not the same as YT `public` Thanks

Comment: Would that mean that the last answer on the reference url https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642579/how-can-i-download-a-video-from-facebook-using-graphapi should be the correct answer now? It was downvoted twice.

Comment: Well it wasn’t necessarily the right answer at the time it was given (that thread is almost older than some of the kids that are on Facebook these days by now ;-)), but seems to have morphed into the right one now with the current changes Facebook is making (mostly due to the Cambridge Analytica scandal) ...

Comment: yup I know that. Just trying to get the attention of the moderators for updates :)

Answer (score 4):

I faced the same problem after the latest API changes from Facebook. The solution I came up, was to parse the video's URL and I'm using the following function.

```
function getFacebookVideoFromUrl($url) {
    $context = [
        'http' => [
        'method' => 'GET',
        'header' => "User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/51.0.2704.47 Safari/537.36",
        ],
    ];
    $context = stream_context_create($context);
    $data = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);

    $regex = '/hd_src_no_ratelimit:"([^"]+)"/';
    if (preg_match($regex, $data, $match)) {
        return $match[1];
    } else {
        $regex = '/sd_src_no_ratelimit:"([^"]+)"/';
        if (preg_match($regex, $data, $match)) {
            return $match[1];
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```