# Is it still possible to download public Facebook Videos via GraphAPI?

Tags: facebook-graph-api, video

I'm trying to get Facebook Video Links which are MP4. I'm using the GraphAPI for it but all I get is:
message100 or message 200.
Is there anyone who can help me out and can explain how it would work?
Already tried it this way:
[How can I download a video from Facebook using GraphAPI?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8642579/how-can-i-download-a-video-from-facebook-using-graphapi/16921188)

Comment: With this way of typing i get the error code 10:

Comment: https://graph.facebook.com/v10.0/1576010435073451?fields=source&access_token=EABLABLALf4Tz0MYBAAZC0ZCrvC27FCQyYfKem6EUJh6dI6Qs8MQbqFbsEgZCDoSHwgCFYk61YxzWcfgDni5mtlLBVjZA5ZBcLdNH8i7ZATuHC4gA2lqpcl7JRp0xU2XPBVHDEPsrae3GKNLhRN3qfxZCI3hc9U0KhEcRDdC342TmxWKb1zz0F3hCP1Tn9B6pnFq7FKido0kRQOazQZDZD

Comment: so still not available, even if the video is public